# How to perform a while loop with a callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, callback, lodash

so i'm trying to reproduce a simpler version of the lodash function takeWhile. To do so i need to use a callback function and i assume i'm going to have to use a while loop which i'm not sure how to implement inside of my function.

Here is what i thought made the most sense but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
const data1 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 2, -1, 2, 4, 5];

const takeUntil = function(array, callback) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (callback(array[i]) === false) {
      result.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
} 

const testOne = takeUntil(data1, x => x < 0);
console.log(testOne);
```

the expected result is to make a string identical to the original one but only until the callback evaluates to true, so in the example it would be as soon as one of the numbers is smaller than 0.

Comment: why do you have two loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your break conditional needs to be on the for, not an inner while.

```js
const data1 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 2, -1, 2, 4, 5];

const takeUntil = function(array, callback) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length && callback(array[i]) === false; i++) {
      result.push(array[i]);
  }
  return result;
} 

const testOne = takeUntil(data1, x => x < 0);
console.log(testOne);
```